# firebase.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts flutterfire_cli error

Tags: flutter, firebase

firebase : File C:\Users\kami\AppData\Roaming\npm\firebase.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts
is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- firebase --version
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

Answer (score 3):

**This could be due to the current user having an undefined ExecutionPolicy.**

Run PowerShell as Administrator, you could try the following:

> Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

copy the above command and paste it on powershell the press **Enter**.
and then type ***A*** and **Enter**